# Prove the set $\{x \in K : x \text{ is algebraic over }F\}$ is a subfield of $K$, containing $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 29, Exercise G2.

> Let F be a field, and K a finite extension of F. Prove the set $\{x \in K : x \text{ is algebraic over }F\}$ is a subfield of $K$, 
>   containing $F$.

Let $S=\{x \in K : x \text{ is algebraic over }F\}$.
Note $F(x_0,x_1,\dots)$ for $x_i\in S$ is a minimal field extension of $F$, and every element in $F(x_0,x_1,\dots)$ is algebraic over $F$.

1. $a\in S\implies a\in F(x_0,x_1,\dots)$ by construction. Hence $S\subseteq F(x_0,x_1,\dots)$.
2. $F(x_0,x_1,\dots)\subseteq K$, so $a\in F(x_0,x_1,\dots)\implies a\in K$.
   As $a$ is algebraic over $F$, $a\in F(x_0,x_1,\dots)\implies a\in S$. 
   Hence $F(x_0,x_1,\dots)\subseteq S$.

Therefore $S=F(x_0,x_1,\dots)$ and $F\subseteq S\subseteq K$.

Is this a reasonable argument?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $S$ is finite. Why is it so? Consider the case that $F = \Bbb Q$.

Comment: You wrote "$F(x_0, \ldots, x_n)$ for $x_i \in S$" is finite. It seemed that you were asserting that $S = \{x_0, \ldots, x_n\}$. In any case, $S$ being a finite extension of $F$ is still not true, in general. ($F = \Bbb Q$ is a counterxample.)

Comment: "$K$ is a finite extension of $F$" -- does that mean finite dimensional (i.e. degree), finitely generated, or something else? If it's finite degree -- the most common meaning of "finite extension" in this context, I think -- then every element of $K$ has finite degree over $F$ and hence is algebraic over $F$, i.e. $S = K$. You seem to be assuming it means finitely generated, but I'm not sure (even without any finiteness assumption, the result is true by Juan's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument seems fine, but I think adjoining all the algebraic elements is a bit overkill.

A simpler way to do it is just to use the exercise right before this one, exercise G1:

If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic over $F$, then $a+b$, $a-b$, $ab$, and $a/b$ (when $b\ne 0$) are algebraic over $F$.

> We have $F \subset S=\{x \in K : x \text{ is algebraic over }F\}$ since every element of $F$ is algebraic over itself; hence $S \ne \varnothing$. If $a, b \in S$, then they are algebraic, so $a\pm b, ab \in S$ and $b^{-1} = 1/b \in S$ when $b \ne 0$.  So, $S$ is a subfield.

Comment: Before reading your answer, let me give it a shot:  By part 1, all the elements in $S$ form a field. As $x\in S\implies x\in K$, $S$ is a subfield of $K$.